# Display Arrays Data In Custom Order In PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to show array data in custom order.

My sample array is :

```
['a' => 'a', 
'b' => 'b', 
'c' => 'c', 
'd' => 'd', 
'e' => 'e', 
'f' => 'f',]
```

**I have tried with the following code :**

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($support_others as $other) {
        echo "<td>" . $other ."</td>";
        $count++;
        if ((($count % 3) == 0) && ($count > 0)) {
            echo ("</tr><tr>");
        }
    }
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

*Its display the order as*

a  b  c

d  e  f

**But I want to display as :**

a  d

b  e

c  f

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I always like messing around with loops with two counters for things like this. Check out this solution:

```
<?php

$support_others = [
  'a' => 'a', 
  'b' => 'b', 
  'c' => 'c', 
  'd' => 'd', 
  'e' => 'e', 
  'f' => 'f'
];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>

    <?php

      for ($i = 'a', $j = 'd'; $i < 'd', $j < 'g'; $i++, $j++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $support_others[$i] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $support_others[$j] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }

    ?>

  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

For a more generalized version, see here:

```
<?php

    $columnOneStart = 'a';
    $columnOneEnd = 'c';

    $columnTwoStart = 'd';
    $columnTwoEnd = 'f';

      for ($i = $columnOneStart, $j = $columnTwoStart; $i <= $columnOneEnd, $j <= $columnTwoEnd; $i++, $j++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $support_others[$i] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $support_others[$j] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }

?>
```

Comment: how would it be possible to display for larger array? lets say 60 items. each row 20 items with 3 columns?

Comment: @HappyNinja See if you can work that out on your own! I'll edit my answer and make it more 'general' so you can see how the boundary conditions work. If you can't figure it out after a little trial and error, I will help you out some more.

Comment: OK, you have 60 items, and you want items 1-20 in column 1, 21-40 in column 2, and 41-60 in column 3 correct? Can you see now how to adjust the example above to fit your needs?

Comment: i got your example with limited data. How will it be generalized for larger array - any idea?

Comment: Yes I know how to do this I'm trying to help you to do it yourself so you can learn how this works though. Can you see that in my generalized version (the second portion of my answer), the loop counters are set to columnOneStart/columnTwoStart and the loop-continuation condition is set to columnOneEnd/columnTwoEnd. Using that, can you see how to extend this to have a columnThreeStart, and columnThreeEnd?

Answer (score 0):

On this kind of table display, the key is the number of element per row which let you calculate the number of rows and the first element of the row.
Once this has been found, you just have to add the number of the column to make your "pointer" move to "rows" element.

```
<?php

$example = [
    'a' => 'a', 
    'b' => 'b', 
    'c' => 'c', 
    'd' => 'd', 
    'e' => 'e', 
    'f' => 'f'
];
$elements = range('a', 'z');

function customTable($elements, $elementsPerRow = 2){
    $elements = array_values($elements);
    $count = count($elements);

    // Prevent empty cols and unallowed (<0 && >n)
    $elementsPerRow = !($elementsPerRow < $count/2 && $elementsPerRow > 0)
        ? (($elementsPerRow > $count) ? $count : 1)
        : $elementsPerRow;
    $rows = ceil($count / $elementsPerRow);

    $table = '<table>';
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i){
        $table .= '<tr>';
        for($j = 0; $j < $elementsPerRow; ++$j){
            $table .= '<td>' . (isset($elements[$j*$rows+$i]) ? $elements[$j*$rows+$i] : '') . '</td>';
            // For debug purpose only
            $table .= '<td>' . ($j*$rows+$i) . '</td>';

        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    return $table . '</table>';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse : collapse; margin: 1em;}
        td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo customTable($elements, 2);
echo customTable($elements, 3);
echo customTable($elements, 4);
echo customTable($elements, 30);
echo customTable($example, 2);
?>
</body>
</html>
```